# Is it ok to delete a dynamically allocated array in master rank after I scattered it to all processes in MPI?

Tags: c++, mpi, dynamic-arrays

I tried to writte a code about jacobi iterative solver using dynamic 
    arrays. My question is if it is proper to delete an array after 
    scattering to all processes.(I'm talking about b_local,A_local)

```
double *b_local;
double *A_local;
int size;
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);   
int rank;
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&rank);    
if (rank==0){
    b_local=new double[n];
    A_local=new double[n*n];
    cout<<"Enter talerance,number of iterations"<<endl;
    cin>>tol;
    cin>>max_iter;
    //Create A and scatter it to all process
    CreateMatrix(A_local);
    //Create b and scatter it to all process    
    CreateVector(b_local);

}
//data init
double *A=new double[n*n/size];
double *b=new double[n/size];
double *x_out=new double[n/size];
//brocast tol,max_iter to all processes
MPI_Bcast(&tol,1,MPI_DOUBLE,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);//send to all processes
MPI_Bcast(&max_iter,1,MPI_INT,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);    
//scatter vector b.Each process takes n/size
MPI_Scatter(b_local,n/size,MPI_DOUBLE,b,n/size,MPI_DOUBLE,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);//here n_local cause we have only one column
//scatter it to all processes
MPI_Scatter(A_local,(n/size)*n,MPI_DOUBLE,A,(n/size)*n,MPI_DOUBLE,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);//n_local*n--->number of elements in n/size rows
if (rank==0){
 delete [] b_local;
 delete [] A_local;
}
```

Comment: That is the part of my code that im not sure about

Comment: `int size;enter code here` <-- that won't compile. Please make sure that example code you post compiles and constitute a [mcve].

Comment: Why are you using manual memory management (raw `new` and `delete`) rather than containers and/or smart pointers in the first place?

Comment: @JesperJuhl I'm using them just for practice.I know with container or smart pointers would be easier but i wanted to try this method.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I agree! However, `MPI` only provides a C interface, encouraging this bad behaviour...

Answer (score 2):

For the code you posted, it is hard to say if it is okay to delete the arrays because some parts are missing.

In general however, [`MPI_Scatter`](https://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.1/www3/MPI_Scatter.html) and [`MPI_Bcast`](https://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.1/www3/MPI_Scatter.html) are blocking calls. This means the code will only continue if these function calls were finished successfully. (This does not mean, that all processes are finished though.) `MPI` might still finish up some things under the hood, but as far as your code is concerned, it is done. Therefore, it is safe to delete data you put inside these functions because `MPI` no longer accesses them after the call.

**Sidenote:**

This has already been pointed out in the comments, but I stress it again: It is much easier to use smart pointers for managing memory instead of using raw `new` and `delete`. You can even keep the C style arrays! For example:

```
#include <memory>

...

std::unique_ptr<double[]> b = std::make_unique<double[]>(n/size);

//at the callsites use b.get() instead of b
```

This approach allows the compiler to automatically delete the point (with its content) if it is no longer used. In addition, you cannot forget to call `delete` plus exceptions are handled correctly.

Alternatively you could just use `std::vector` and pass the `.data()` pointer to `MPI`.

**Addition:**

If you plan to use `MPI` for a while and don't like to wrestle with the C interface, you should consider using a C++ wrapper library like [Boost.MPI](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/doc/html/mpi.html).

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply!Im asking because after the A_local's and b_local's delete I'm using the receive data from MPI_Scatter for some other calculations so im worried if this causes any trouble to my code as i free the send buffer's memory

Comment: @SpyrosArvanitis As long as you are not using the `A_local` and `b_local` at the master again, you should be fine.

Comment: @Evg Thanks. Fixed it.

Comment: "MPI_Scatter and MPI_Bcast are blocking calls. This means the code will only continue if the MPI_Scatter and/or MPI_Bcast were correctly executed on all machines." That is not correct since the MPI standard does not mandate any kind of synchronization (e.g. explicit/implicit `MPI_Barrier()`. That being said, it is correct the send/recv buffers can be freed right after a subroutine completes since these are blocking collectives.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet I don't understand. What are you saying?

Comment: What I understand from your answer is that `MPI_Bcast()` will return once invoked by __all__ tasks. This is not correct, since `MPI_Bcast()` can return much earlier (with short message, root rank very likely returns even if it is not invoked by the non root ranks). same thing for `MPI_Scatter()`

Comment: But the master cannot finish sending if the others aren't receiving, or am I wrong?

Comment: @jan.sende, data you're sending will be buffered inside MPI if necessary.

Comment: Just like `MPI_Send()` can return if no matching receive was posted, `MPI_Bcast()` can return on the root rank if no `MPI_Bcast()` was invoked on the other ranks.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet @ Evg I had a look at the standard again, and you are right. No synchronization is required. Plus, MPI processes may be able to finish before everyone else. However, I don't see why this matters. If the data was sent, it was sent. Why should I care about every process starting the next step at the same time? Sure, this means I don't have time synchronization, but in a way, I still get logical synchronization.

Comment: My only point was that “This means the code will only continue if the MPI_Scatter and/or MPI_Bcast were correctly executed on all machines." is incorrect and you should edit your answer and correct it. FWIW, if you do not have any kind of synchronization, then the non root ranks might receive too many unexpected messages and use a lot of memory (that is why Open MPI has the `coll/sync` module). Also I do not know what logical synchronization is.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet I fixed the description. Is it to your liking now? ... Also, I see the point of synchronization now. I never considered it, because I try to send as few messages as possible in my code anyways... Overflowing is therefore no concern for me. ... With the logical synchronization I meant, that the code is always valid (besides overflow) and you cannot run into issues with processes posting receives without sends, ...

Answer (score 0):

`MPI_Scatter` is a blocking operation, which is complete as soon as the call returns. So, after `MPI_Scatter` returns, you can reuse the buffer and, in particular, delete it. In contrast, `MPI_Iscatter` is a non-blocking operation. You have to wait for the completion before safely reusing the buffer.